# I am using angular2 for my website ,and I got EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Access is denied.In IE 11

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, angular-cli

I developed a web site using angular2.IT is working fine with "http://somthingxyz.com"in all the browser.But When I am using "https://somthingxyz.com" then I got EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Access is denied.In IE 11.

How can I use base url with "https".If I set the base URL with http then It is working well.But when I set my base URL with "https" Then I got the EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Access is denied.In IE 11
[image]

How can I resolve the above error.

// This file includes polyfills needed by Angular 2 and is loaded before
// the app. You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

Comment: Are you sure that is an angular error and not an error thrown by a service for improper access to the resource ?

Comment: This is not happening in another browsers(Chorme,Firefox,Safari) and also working in "http://localhost:4200" in IE browser.So I m in confused with IE fix or server fix.                                                                                Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably due to IE security zone feature. Try adding your origin site to the "Trusted sites" security zone.

Comment: I added origin site to "Trusted sites",But Now I got the error in IE .SCRIPT5009: 'webpackJsonp' is undefined

Comment: Do you have any js file define in your index.html? That would be one of the issue for that error.., Also I assumed that you included the required polyfills for IE support?

Comment: I have not added any js file index index.html.Could you suggest me required polyfills for IE support.I want to add below link to index.html file.                                                                     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.33.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.20/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>

Comment: Angular cli have its own. In the polyfills.ts file uncomment the imports. All information is there in the file.

Comment: I uncomment but not fixed.I added polyfills.ts in my code above.