# Uncaught (In Promise): Error: Access Denied in IE11

Tags: javascript, angular-cli, internet-explorer-11, angular7

Am using Angular 7 in my project and I found this error last day. It is happening only in the deployed site. Not in my local. Also the same issue is not throwing in any other browsers, but in IE11 (Haven't tried any lower versions of IE). This issue was not there before and its been happening from last day only. I tried to figure out the issue. Tried changing polyfills and so on. But nothing worked. Tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45498800/i-am-using-angular2-for-my-website-and-i-got-exception-uncaught-in-promise) also. But that is also not resolved. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you add your code ?

Comment: Which code do you need?

Answer (score 1):

The reason your `Promises` are causing errors in IE is that `Promises` are not supported in IE11.

Although, there are ways to add support for them:

- 3rd Party `Promise` libraries (ie: [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html))
- If you are using ES6 syntax, perhaps use a transpiler (ie: [Babel](https://babeljs.io/))

[Current support for promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Thanks for this reply. Let me try this method. In between, as I said, it was all working before and the issue started to pop out from last day only. So why would be that odd behavior if Promises were causing the issue?

Comment: Is it possible that this block of code was not hit when you tested on IE?

Comment: No way. There is only one API calling from the landing page and I don't think there is a chance it might be skipped.

Comment: Well, either way, are the promises implemented in a way that is IE11 (and lower) safe? Because that would be a problem in itself

Comment: I used this package `https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-polyfill`. And the error exists still.